# Is there a way to change text on site reload?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reload

If there's a good equivalent to what I'm trying to accomplish, it'd be the Minecraft splash text that changes every time you open the main menu of the game.

Would there be a way to accomplish that with java in an HTML doc? Below I have what I've already tried but as of right now I'm lost.

```
$(function() {
    var splashes = ["example_text1", "example_text2", "example_text3"];
    $("#subtitle").html($("#subtitle").html().replace("text0", splashes[Math.floor(Math.random()*splashes.length)]));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try reading about [Repaints and Reflows](https://medium.com/darrja-%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9C%E0%A4%BE/what-the-heck-is-repaint-and-reflow-in-the-browser-b2d0fb980c08)

Asides from that, you could create a rendering function, and call it every time the user uses the button to return to the main menu.

So

```
repaintDom() => {
 *your code*
}
```

then

```
document.querySelector('.your-button').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    repaintDom();
})
```